# I am confused implementing forgot password functionality in fortify

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

With fortify in Laravel 8 I want to make
forgot-password functionality and in app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php I wrote :

```
Fortify::requestPasswordResetLinkView(function () {
    return view('auth.forgot-password');
});

Fortify::resetPasswordView(function ($request) {
    return view('auth.reset-password', ['request' => $request]);
});
```

I filled template auth.forgot-password with design I use for enering 1 email and I recieive
email with content :

> You are receiving this email because we received a password reset
> request for your account.
>
> Reset Password This password reset link will expire in 60 minutes.
>
> If you did not request a password reset, no further action is ....

1. I want to replace content of this email, but I failed to find it and how can I replace it with my template?
2. Is value “60 minutes” configurable? How  can I do it ?
3. Opening link in email above I see form with 3 fields Email, Password, Confirm Password. That is auth.reset-password
   template and I can modify it. But I can not understand what for  Password and Confirm Password inputs?
   It looks like I want to modify user's password inside user's profile.
   I am very confused what this functionality is for ? How can I implement forgot password functionality in fortify ?

I have  config/fortify.php :

```
'features' => [
    Features::registration(),
    Features::resetPasswords(),
    // Features::emailVerification(),
    Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
        'confirmPassword' => true,
    ]),
],
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer question 2.
Go to auth.php file, change the value at 'expire' to whatever you want.

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 0,
    ],
],
```

The great issue here, is that I changed here and doesn't work. So if that works for you, please let me know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).